# On functions that are bounded by other certain functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I am trying to address a specific, but also rather abstract, problem, which briefly can be stated as follows:

Let $f$, $g$ be real-valued functions defined for all column vectors in $\Re^n$, i.e.,

$$
f,g:\Re^n \rightarrow \Re.
$$

It would be extremely desired to find a (family of) function(s) $g$ that is bounded as follows:

$$
0 \leq g(\mathbf{x}) \leq f(\mathbf{x}), \forall \mathbf{x}\in\Re^n.
$$

I am particularly interested in those cases for which $f$ is in the following form:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = K exp \left\{  -\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}  \right\}
$$

I am not sure whether there's a feasible approach to do so or not, while I am not deeply familiarized with issues concerning function bounding.

Could anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, if we select the $g$ functions to be of the following form

$$
g(\mathbf{x}) = \lambda
exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}\right\},
$$

then

$$
0 \leq g(\mathbf{x}) \leq Kexp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}\right\} \Rightarrow 
0 \leq \lambda \leq K,
$$

which I think is correct, but I would like to find something more sophisticated...

Anyone? Thanks!